# Partial upgrade for Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS removed Steam – move existing Steam games to Snap or Flatpak installation or reinstall?

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, update-manager, steam, partial-upgrade

On Aug 4, 2023 the Software Updater tool offered a partial upgrade for Ubuntu which included the removal of the Steam Installer.

And indeed so it happened, Steam and the starters to my installed Steam games disappeared from the system. This is not nice.
Then I reinstalled Steam. 3 Versions were available: 1.0.0.78 from flathub.org, 1.0.0.76 from Snapcraft.io and 1.0.0.74 as "Steam Installer" Ubuntu deb.

But with either the Flatpak version or the Snap version all my previously installed and still existing games are invisible. Linux games as well as Windows games with GE-Proton.

As a quick fix, I reinstalled the Ubuntu (deb) version. Login and settings were still intact and all installed games are visible in Steam, however the starters seem to be permanently removed.

Why was Steam suddenly removed?
How can I easily import or move my installed games and settings to the Flatpak or Snapcraft version of Steam?
Should I/must I?

Comment: @user535733 There is no mention of Steam and I did not have the same problems mentioned there, though it might be related.

Comment: However, my question is now specific about Steam and which installation variant I should keep. The Snap variant is provided by Canonical so I presume, removing the packaged version was kind of intended, but it was a bad move like this because settings and games seem to be inaccessible after installing the Snap version.

Comment: FWIW, I had no issues with Steam after that update, and I use the deb version as well. I would recommend against switching to the snap or flatpak version and just recreate your launchers manually.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian. Yes, I am using the "old" deb version now. Luckily, the starters were recreated too, they were just not yet visible in the launcher right after I installed Steam and started it once.